# Component is not updating in react-native after executing task using redux structure

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, jsx

I'm building an App using react-native , following redux concepts , now i got stucked in a problem ,my component is not updating as they should after dispatching an action.

Explaining the plot a bit, I have a React Class "QuestionScreen" and i want to make a call to an API as soon as the page opens but a loader should be rendered while API is doing its work and when its done , questions should appear.so here is my code below

PS: Im new react native and super new to redux concept so a little help with explanation would be nice

**QuestionScreen.js**

```jsx
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        session: state.questionsReducer.session
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
}

class QuestionsScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        title: `${navigation.state.params.title}`,
        headerRight: <Button transparent><EntypoIcon name="dots-three-vertical"/></Button>,
        headerTintColor: '#0b3484',
    });

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            params: this.props.navigation.state.params.passProps
        };

        this.fetchSessionQuestions = this.fetchSessionQuestions.bind(this);
    }

    fetchSessionQuestions() {
        this.props.fetchPracticeQuesions({
            URL: BASE_URL + '/api/dashboard/get_chapter_question/',
            chapter: this.state.params.chapter_name
        });

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchSessionQuestions();

    }

    render() {


        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

        if (this.props.session.isLoading) {
            return (
                // Loader here
            );
        }
        else {

            const questions = this.props.session.questions;

            return (

                // Some questions logic here

            );
        }

    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(QuestionsScreen);
```

**questionsReducer.js**

```jsx
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    session: {
        isLoading: true,
        currentQuestion: 0,
        questions: [],
        score: 0,
        timeTaken: 0,
        attempted: 0
    }
};

const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState));

export default function questionsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.NEXT_QUESTION:
            newState.session.currentQuestion = newState.session.currentQuestion + action.payload;
            return newState;
        case types.FETCH_PRACTICE_QUESTION:

            fetch(action.payload.URL, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: 'student',
                    password: 'pass1234',
                    chapter: action.payload.chapter
                })
            }).
            then((response) => response.json()).
            then((responseJson) => {
                newState.session.questions = responseJson;
                newState.session.isLoading = false;
            });
             console.log(newState);
            return newState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

now the probelem im having is that the props.session in my QuestionScreen remains same, so a loader keeps on spinning, even after dispatching that action, what should i do now ??

and yeah one more thing i checked the states status in console using logger and thunk middleware, the state printed there is as expected , showing me correct value there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use middleware as Redux-Thunk to implement async actions. Also you shouldn't use fetch in reducer, you should dispatch 3 events instead on request begin, request success, and request errors. Something like this:

```js
export const callApi = ((fetchUrl) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(requestBegin());
  let body = (method === 'GET') ? undefined : JSON.stringify(data);
  return fetch(fetchUrl, {
    method,
    body,
  })
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then(function(data) {
    dispatch(requestSuccess(data);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    dispatch(requestError(data));
  })  
});
```

Also, you can read about async actions [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html)

Comment: thanks i was  scratching my head for 2 days for this solution , thanks it worked :)